# git push err fail to push some refs to host

Tags: git, gitlab

When I run "git push origin master",I got this error:

```
sam@SAM-PC /C/Users/sam/Desktop/diandao_web/diandaoWeb (master)
$ git push origin master
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: No such project
To git@123.57.226.209:diandao/diandaoWeb.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to   'git@123.57.226.209:diandao/diandaoWeb.git'
```

How do i resolve this problem?

Comment: There seems to be no such project. Are you sure you have created a project?

Comment: I think diandaoWeb  have some commit hook which might  require some mandatory information in your git message or your branch is protected.

Comment: @RishiSaraf THX, I wll check the info of hook protection with the man in charge of the update of hook.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with you not having write-access to the branch, see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/145

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error is pretty clear:

> ```
> remote: GitLab: No such project
> ```

Check that the origin URL you used is correct and that the user `diandao` actually has a project named `diandaoWeb` on *that* GitLab instance.